# Snowflake Row count "G" meaning

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using snowflake for the first time, and I noticed that row counts in the billions (288,010,550,524) is represented as 288.0G (for the TPCDS_SF100TCL SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA set).

What exactly does "G" mean?
I've seen smaller row counts represented in K (thousands), M (Millions), but not B (Billions).

Sounds like a simple and silly question, but I've never seen row counts represented with that quantifier and wanted to know what it was.
It's also not documented in the snowflake documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefixes/factors are:

```
           factor   name
k - kilo   10^3     thousand
M - mega   10^6     million
G - giga   10^9     billion
```

Related: [Metric prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix)/[Giga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giga-)

---

SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA -> Tables -> STORE_SALES -> Rows

```
<div data-qtip="<b>Row Count: 288.0G (288,010,550,524)</b>">288.0G</div>
```

So `288.0G` means `288.0 * 10^9 rows`.

Comment: But that scale is for data quantity, not row count?

Comment: In that article, here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#Similar_symbols_and_abbreviations

It refers to K, M, B, and T for "large quantities". I've seen these quantities in several other data warehouses, and when referring to row counts. 

I've never heard anyone quote a row count as "288 giga rows"

Comment: @Lazarix It is more like a [factor](https://www.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/metric-si-prefixes) than prefix which means 288 * 10^9 rows or 288 billion rows

Comment: @Lazarix another way to look at this is they have one "pretty print" function, that takes large numbers and makes them pretty, and they first did file size, and thus went with `G` for `GB` and didn't have a parameter to size rows or bytes, so when the pretty function is used on rows, because there is a billion, there you get `G`. It's always been this way, and after about 10 seconds of wondering why, I found I could just get back on with writing meaningful sql and not be bothered.

Comment: Haha! Fair enough @simeon, I agree the issue is entirely inconsequential, but at the same time it bugs me. I'm kind of thinking, if something so simple is so wrong, what else in the product is going to be suffering from the same lack of attention to detail...

Comment: @Lazarix reading the linked wiki page, it's actually correct, but different to what one might expect. but it's also pretty printing, and thus, just for human reading. So there is nothing structurally wrong, it's just units that are perhaps not your personal native form. Perhaps like kilometer vs miles, both correct, just maybe different.